# Add 1 month to Feb 28 should result to March 31

Tags: java, calendar, jodatime, gregorian-calendar

I am trying to add 1 month on dates but the problem is when I have a date of Feb 28 then I add another month, I result to March 28. It should end on March 31. Same as when I started with a date of April 30, I should end in May 31 not May 30. I tried using plusMonths() of Jodatime and add() of java.util.date but still same problem.

Comment: So if it would be Feb 2 and you add a month, what date would you expect then?

Comment: that would be march 2.

Comment: Would 28 Feb 2013 advance to 31 March 2013 but 28 Feb 2016 advance to 28 Mar 2016?

Comment: @EricJablow yes. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your expectation is simply wrong: it is supposed to move to the same day in the following month, if such exists. Anyway, how can the code know that you want Feb 28 to mean "the last day of February"? It legitimately means "the 28th day of February". Suppose you started with Jan 28, then added a month, then added one more, what result would you expect?

What you need can be achieved by working with the 1st of the following month and then moving one day back.

Comment: If the date started with January 28, it should end in Feb 28, then next month would be march 28. But if the date started with Jan 31, next month should be feb 28, then march 31. Is this possible?

Comment: The logic you suggest would have to be the function of the complete history of the object's states. It would also be highly specific to your wishes. Naturally, no public library caters for that.